# Facebook Comments - Not appearing on user's profile once approved

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I was determined to resolve this through myself through research and testing, but I'm just at an absolute loss now so I'll unleash this on the community.

First, my comments set-up for reference:

Meta Tag for Moderation:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="[my AppId]"/>
```

FB Root and FB.init (top of BODY)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>window.fbAsyncInit = function () { FB.init({ appId: '[my APPid]', xfbml: true, version: 'v2.3' }); };</script>
```

FB Comments Tag

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="[the page URL]" num_posts="5" width="100%" data-version="v2.3"></div>
```

FB SDK Call (at bottom of body)

```
(function (d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; } js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

**The issue:**

- I have the FB Comments code on my page and the commments block is
  rendering fine.
- I click inside the comments fields and make a       comment, also
  clicking POST TO FACEBOOK.
- I log in as a user (not the app owner) as prompted and make my
  comment, this comment appears on the article page after a few
  seconds.
- I log in another machine as the App Owner, I can see the comment is
  ready for moderation so I click APPROVE. It greys out as Approved.
- Back to the USER machine, clicking through to view the user's own
  profile, the comment is not displayed as a post.

**What I need:**
The comment to display on user's profile once app owner has approved it.

**What I've tried and found:**

- If I DISABLE moderation by simple removing the fb:app_id Meta Tag,
  the post DOES appear on the user's profile when ALSO POST TO FB is
  clicked.
- If I ENABLE moderation, the comment appears on the article even from
  a THIRD PARTY (as in a totally other machine on a session not even
  logged into FB) even before moderation has been approved!!

Comment: Looks like there are two issue here. I would double check your comment settings from the page itself or from the [comments tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments). If all looks fine, then I would report this as a bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs (I would recommend reporting separate bugs for each issue since they don't seem related)